# Not being able to get next textarea working

Tags: php, jquery, textarea

I have a textarea after a div and I'm using rangyinputs to insert some text in that area, like surrounding etc.

If I use the following code it works:

```
window.surround5 = function surround5(text2,text3){
$("#textarea5").surroundSelectedText(text2, text3);
}
```

being textarea5 the class name, but I didnt wanted to use class name so I tried with:

```
window.surroundtest = function surroundtest(text2,text3){
var c = $(this).next('textarea');
c.surroundSelectedText(text2, text3);
}
```

But It keeps getting me some error about nodes on rangyinputs that doesnt show in the other way. If I do a alert it shows "object object" so its actually finding the textarea right?

The implementation would be for something like:

```
<div>
<div onclick="surroundtest('[center]', '[/center]');">Center</div>
</div>
<textarea ....>
```

Edited with the div that is making the call.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/qmpY8/

Comment: Can you tell us the html that you are manipulating?.

Comment: `$(this).parent().next('textarea');` is what you are after me thinks

Comment: Orange tried that as well, didnt worked. @BetoCastillo its like the example above, some divs and one in the middle that does the calling. and the textarea is after the ending div

Comment: I don't see any classes or id's defined in your html code. It will easier to you if you use class or id's.

Comment: @BetoCastillo because I dont want to use that, I will clone this entire code so I didnt wanted to name the textarea. I'll edit the div that calls.

Comment: Well, added jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, in jQuery, if you want to select an element by class, you do it by

```
$('.elementClass') //Select one or more element by class
```

The # selector is for id's, not classes.

```
$('#elementId') //Select one element by id
```

Hope it helps.

If you only want to select the textarea. And only if is just one textarea.

As simply like this:

```
$('textarea')
```

I still don't get you persistence in don't use id's or class.

The way i would solve it, is passing the id to the function, so, in this way, it doesnt matter how many textareas appears on the html.

```
<div>
<div class="guides_chapters_button" onclick="surround('[center]', '[/center]', 'textareamatch');">Center</div>
<div class="guides_chapters_button" style="text-decoration: underline;" onclick="surround('[u]','[ u/]', 'textareamatch');">u</div>
```

```
window.surround = function surround(text2,text3, id){
    $("#" + id).surroundSelectedText(text2, text3);
}
```

I tested and it's works.
http://jsfiddle.net/wNrWC/

Greetings from México.

Comment: I dont want to select by class or ID, I want to select the next textarea.

Comment: Thanks I guess I dont have any other option :x The problem is now when I clone it, I will have to edit that text on the onclick to the new id. that will be complicated.